# Sql Filteration query

Tags: sql, group-by

In my table `SpecimenSite` column will have repeated data.

I need to look into `SpecimenGroup` column to check it contains **Data** or **Other** value.

If I got **Data** and **Other**, it means I need to avoid that column. 
If I get only the **other**, it means I need to show *other* in column.

What Am having now in table given below

[image: Original Table Data]

What i expect to display given below

[image: Expected Table Data]

Assume that if my table doesn't have the value of **A** as **SAMPLE** mean it need to display like this

[image: Another Scenario]

Comment: I....really don't understand what it is that you want....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you want to suppress rows that have **Other** in the SpecimenGroup unless there are no other SpecimenGroups for the SpecimenSite.

```
select specimen1.specimensite, specimen1.specimengroup 
from specimen specimen1
left join specimen specimen2
on specimen1.specimensite=specimen2.specimensite
and specimen2.specimengroup <> 'Other'
where specimen1.specimengroup <> 'Other'
or specimen2.specimengroup is null
group by specimen1.specimensite, specimen1.specimengroup
```

Comment: It works for me thanks. but if got only other means it have to show other.

Comment: Yes, it should be doing that. The "or specimen2.specimengroup is null" should select "Other" as long as there is nothing else for the specimengroup..

Answer (score 0):

Select specimen and check for existence of same site, but different group when you have group = other.

```
select *
from Specimen as s1
where not exists(
  select *
  from Specimen as s2
  where s2.SpecimenSite = s1.SpecimenSite
  and s2.SpecimenGroup != s1.SpecimenGroup
  and s1.SpecimenGroup = 'Other'
)
```